# Why isn't Drupal's core once() function working in my simple test script?

Tags: javascript, 10

I am trying to console.log a message once and only once in Drupal 10.  I am cutting and pasting examples from https://www.drupal.org/node/3158256 into my file and I am still seeing the message appear multiple times in the console.

I have added the dependencies to the library:

```
my-library:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/my-library.js: { }
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/once
```

And I have this simple test script in which I have cut & paste the example code from https://www.drupal.org/node/3158256

```
(function ($, Drupal, once) {
  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
    'attach': function attach(context, settings) {

      once('init-once', context === document ? 'html' : context)
      .forEach(function initOnce(doc) {
        console.log('init-once', doc);
      });

    }

  };

})(jQuery, Drupal, once);
```

My goal is simply to console.log a message once and only once. How can I log a message only once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`core/once` isn't for doing something just once, but for attaching a script just once. Then it's up to your script's logic to actually do something just once. You could for example toggle a simple CSS class on the `<body>` tag like `oops-i-did-it` and check in your JS if this class already exists or not before you trigger your magic.

And your libraries definition is missing the `core/jquery` dependency.

Bookmark this change record: https://www.drupal.org/node/3158256, it gives you a few really nice examples on how to use `once()` with and without jQuery. (You know that every times you use jQuery a small kitten dies? )

```yaml
myfeature:
  js: 
    js/myfeature.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/once
```

```javascript
(function (Drupal, once) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myfeature = {
    attach(context) {
      // '[data-myfeature]' in the next line can also be 'div.my-class'
      // or '#my-id' etc.
      const elements = once('myfeature', '[data-myfeature]', context);
      // `elements` is always an Array.
      elements.forEach(processingCallback);
    }
  };

  // `value` in the next line is your actual DOM element. Do something with
  // `value` like `value.classList.add('hello-world')`.
  function processingCallback(value, index) {}
}(Drupal, once));
```

Comment: Haven’t heard the jQuery killing kittens thing for literally years, really made me chuckle 

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works:

```
(function ($, Drupal, once) {
  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
    'attach': function attach(context, settings) {

      if ($(once('my-test', 'body')).length) {
        console.log('my test');
      }

    }
  };

})(jQuery, Drupal, once);
```

Though I can't say I understand the syntax. It seems quite verbose and more difficult to grasp than Jquery .once().

Comment: This isn’t good code - jquery isn’t needed, and converting to a  jquery object just to test the length, when `once` returns a testable result, is just over-engineering. Leymannx’s answer is v. good, that should be preferred

Comment: Jquery is needed, or at least preferable, for the actual feature I was building up to -- but not for the highly simplified console.log example in my answer above.  I ended up not needing `once` for the actual feature, though the answer from leymannx will be a useful reference the next time I consider using `once`.